# R programming remove header and footer from each page

Tags: r

I am trying to export a text file report to excel using R. The report I generate has multiple pages based on the amount of data we have. Each page has a footer and header. I could skip reading the header and footer if there was just one instance of each but I do not know how to skip header and footer for each page.

The report looks something like this on each page:

```
                                  Report Name
                             product version
Date

Column1      column2      column3  ....
data         data          data
data         data          data
.
.
.
data         data          data

                           Report Name
                           Page number
```

Comment: if you have the source code for the report generator why not just remove the pagination header/footer code?

Comment: If you don't have the report generator code, is it safe to assume that any leading white space indicates a header or footer? In that case, it depends on your file-reading function. If using `read.table`, can you `comment.char=" "`?